# Calculation of decision boundaries with Perceptron

Tags: matlab, perceptron

here i will train perceptron and plot decision boundaries (target is generated so I am sure that it is lineary separable). For sake of the example, there is no bias.

```
 numinput=5;
 net=newp([-1 1; -1 1], 1); %2 inputs between -1 and 1, 1 neuron
 net.IW{1,1}=rands(1,2);
 P=rands(2,numinput);
 T=sim(net,P);
 plotpv(P,T);
 hold on;
 plotpc(net.IW{1,1},0);
```

This is the result:
[image]

P has following values:

```
-0.2592   -0.0364    0.3828    0.0246   -0.0691
-0.2451    0.5912    0.6996    0.7101   -0.4703
```

And weights are:

```
-0.3462   -0.7939
```

I understand the idea behind, but how, with those weights, the decision line is plotted?

**Let's say I want plot the chart by hand, how I caculate the line given the weights?**

I know, elementary math, I just cannot see it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With no intercept and two weights ($\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$) as in the OP, the decision boundary line is at:

$0 = \theta_1 x_1 + \theta_2 x_2$

Hence, since the plot is of $x_2$ versus $x_1$, we choose two extreme points along $x_1$ included in the plot (plus some margin) and calculate the expected $x_2$ at the decision boundary:

$\large x_2 = \frac{- \theta_1 x_1} {\theta_2}$

In the OP, the two values along $P(1)$ could be arbitrarily chosen to be $-.7$ and $+.7$, yielding corresponding $P(2)$ values *at the decision boundary line* of $0.3052526$ and $-0.3052526$, respectively. Now it's just a matter of drawing a line between points $(-.7,.305)$ and $(.7,-.305)$.

I guess in Matlab it would only remain to run `x=[-.7,.7]; y=[.305,-.305]; plot(x,y)`, but in R, the whole process would be:

[image]

```
    data=t(as.matrix(data))
    data = cbind(data,c(1,0,0,0,1))
    colnames(data) = c("P(1)","P(2)","classifier")
    rownames(data) = NULL

    plot(data, xlim=c(-.6,.65), ylim=c(-1,1.5),
         pch = c(1,3)[as.factor(data[,3])],
         col = c("blue","red")[as.factor(data[,3])],
         cex=1.5,
         main="Vectors to be Classified")
    abline(h=0)
    abline(v=0)

    min(data[,1])

    x1 = -.7
    x2 = .7
    w1 = -0.3462
    w2 = -0.7939
    y1 = (1/w2) * (- x1 * w1)
    y2 = (1/w2) * (- x2 * w1)

    lines(c(x1,x2),c(y1,y2), lwd = 3, col="darkorange4")
```